# pybind11: convert py::list to std::vector<std::string>

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have the following sample code which obtains a `py::list` as the output of evaluating some python code.

I would like to convert it to a `std::vector<std::string>`, but am getting an error:

> ```
> conversion from 'pybind11::list' to non-scalar type 
>      'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' requested
> ```

Per the [documentation](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/cast/stl.html):

> When including the additional header file `pybind11/stl.h`, conversions
> between
> `std::vector<>`/`std::deque<>`/`std::list<>`/`std::array<>`/`std::valarray<>`,
> `std::set<>`/`std::unordered_set<>`, and `std::map<>`/`std::unordered_map<>`
> and the Python `list`, `set` and `dict` data structures are automatically
> enabled.

As you can see from the below code example, I have included `stl.h`, but automatic conversion doesn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>
#include <pybind11/stl.h>
#include <pybind11/eval.h>

namespace py = pybind11;

py::list func()
{
    py::object scope = py::module_::import("__main__").attr("__dict__");
    return py::eval("[ 'foo', 'bar', 'baz' ]", scope);
}

int main()
{
    Py_Initialize();

    // call the function and iterate over the returned list of strings
    py::list list = func();
    for (auto it : list)
        std::cout << py::str(it) << '\n';

    // error
    // conversion from 'pybind11::list' to non-scalar type 'std::vector<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' requested
    std::vector<std::string> vec = list;
    for (auto str : vec)
        std::cout << str << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

I can iterate over the `py::list` manually and call `vector::push_back` with each element

```
// populating the vector manually myself works
std::vector<std::string> vec;
vec.reserve(list.size());
for (auto it : list)
    vec.push_back(py::str(it));
```

So I guess the linked documentation above only refers to c++ -> python conversions, and not the other way?

What is the recommended way to convert from `py::list` to `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call `.cast<>`:

```cpp
auto vec = list.cast<std::vector<std::string>>();
```

`<pybind11/stl.h>` simply brings specializations of the conversion templates that allow such cast, and that also allow implicit conversion when you bind function with vector arguments or returning vectors (or other standard containers).

Comment: Ah, brilliant, thank you! I knew there had to be a better way than having to unroll the list myself manually!

Comment: If you get "Unable to cast Python instance to C++ type" it's because you haven't included `<pybind11/stl.h>`